# How can we run a report that doesn't split records into multiple entries?

Tags: civireport

We want to run a report on the enquiries/feedback and the outcomes and signposting that result from each one. However, when we run a report it splits each record entered into individual records for 'Enquiries/Feedback', 'Outcome', 'Signposting' etc so they are not joined up and therefore we cannot see what the outcome was of an enquiry or where it was signposted to. How can we do this?
Many thanks

Comment: It would help us all to help you if you specify what CMS and what version of CiviCRM you are using. Also add a little more detail, possibly screen prints so we can understand your issue. Just read your question and I have no clue what you are talking about other than a report that does something you did not expect....

Comment: This is the version we are using: CiviCRM 4.7.22
For some reason I can't add a screenshot to this comment box.
But basically each record that we have entered onto the database gets split out when reporting as if it were a separate entry but we would like it to just be the one entry as when it was entered

Comment: @GeorgeHealthwatch It's best to add screenshots by editing the original question.

Comment: The screenshots will be critical here because CiviCRM is used for a variety of uses - and "Enquiries/Feedback", "Outcome", etc. are terms specific to your usage.  With screenshots, we can tell how they were implemented for you (e.g. as Activities, Cases, etc.) and provide you with appropriate help.

Comment: and the reason you are being asked about your CMS is that Drupal (views) let's you pull together info which is otherwise v hard to do in civicrm

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that these fields containing "enquiries/feedback and the outcomes and signposting" are either custom contact fields with multiple entries or activities. In either case, you probably want to use the report grouping feature to group by contact (e.g. by contact id), that would likely get you closer to what you want. If you sort by id or date of these other things, then you might get a nice chronological display per contact.

If you want a fancier display, you'll likely have to write a custom report.